# Find the sum $\sum _{ k=1 }^{ 100 }{ \frac { k\cdot k! }{ { 100 }^{ k } } } \binom{100}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Find the sum $$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ 100 }{ \frac { k\cdot k! }{ { 100 }^{ k } } } \binom{100}{k}$$

When I asked my teacher how can I solve this question he responded it is very hard, you can't solve it. I hope you can help me in solving and understanding the question.

Comment: If you can edit the title . I will be very grateful

Comment: Thanks for using proper formatting. There were a few errors though that I corrected. Please review my edit to see how to format correctly.

Comment: @probablyme I think the tag `abstract-algebra` is not relevant here.

Comment: Where did you get this sum from? What makes you think it should have a nice solution, if your teacher says it hasn't?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my errors . I will review your edit

Comment: I got it from internet . We are studying the summation and I would like to be perfect in this part of mathematic . so , the questions in my book are very easy. for this reason , I would like to improve my self by the questions in the internet

Comment: It seems like it's equal to $100$, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum+_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B100%7D%7B(%5Cfrac%7B+k!%5Ccdot+k+%7D%7B+100%5Ek+%7D+)(%7B100+%5Cchoose+k%7D)%7D)

Comment: Replace "100" by $N$, and the sum appears to be $N$ from calculating a few values for small $N$.

Comment: I know the solution . I wanna know the way of solving this question

Comment: You mean you know the sum, but want to know the solution?

Comment: .........exactly

Comment: Nice question (+1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} \frac {k\cdot k!}{100^k} \frac{100!}{k!(100-k)!} &= \frac{100!}{100^{100}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} \frac{k\cdot100^{100-k}}{(100-k)!}\\
&= \frac{100!}{100^{100}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{99}\frac{(100-k)\cdot 100^k}{k!}\\ &=\frac{99!}{100^{99}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{99}
\left( \frac {100^{k+1}}{k!} - \frac{100^k}{(k-1)!}\right)\\ &=
\frac{99!}{100^{99}} 
\left(\frac{100^1}{0!}+
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{99} \frac {100^{k+1}}{k!} -
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{98} \frac{100^{k+1}}{k!}\right)\\&=
\frac{99!}{100^{99}} 
\left(\frac{100^1}{0!}+
\frac{100^{100}}{99!} +
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{98} \frac {100^{k+1}}{k!} -
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{98} \frac{100^{k+1}}{k!}
-\frac{100^1}{0!}
\right)\\
&= 
100
\end{align}

Comment: of course. I think my teacher can't solve it

Comment: Now one only needs to show that $100-99!/(100)^{98}=100$

Comment: $\frac{99!}{100^{98}}\approx 9.33\times 10^{-41}\neq 0$

Comment: How can I show that

Comment: I know it is very small . But , it is not zero

Comment: @user309264. It is not while the answer is exactly $100$.

Comment: It seems that if you replace all instances of $100$ with $N$ you get $\sum _{ k=1 }^{ N }{ \frac { k\cdot k! }{ { N }^{ k } } } \binom{N}{k} = N$

Answer (score 5):

Using the notation $n^\underline{r}=\overbrace{n\ (n-1)\ (n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)}^{r\text{  terms}}$ for the  falling factorial , we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {k\cdot k!}{n^k}\binom nk&=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {\color{blue}k\cdot k!}{n^k}\cdot \frac {n^\underline{k}}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {n^\underline{k}}{n^k}\color{blue}{[n-(n-k)]}\\
&=n\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {n^\underline{k}}{n^k}-\frac{n^\underline{k+1}}{n^{k+1}}}_{\text{telescoping sum}}
&&\text{as   }n^\underline{k}(n-k)=n^\underline{k+1}\\
&=n 
&&\text{as  }n^{\underline{n+1}}=0
\end{align}$$

Putting $n=100$ gives
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac {k\cdot k!}{100^k}\binom {100}k=100\qquad\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 4):

I am re-editing a-rodin's answer, correcting a few typos [of an earlier version, now edited].

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} \frac {k\cdot k!}{100^k} \frac{100!}{k!(100-k)!} &= \frac{100!}{100^{100}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} \frac{k\cdot100^{100-k}}{(100-k)!}\\
&= \frac{100!}{100^{100}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{99}\frac{(100-k)\cdot 100^k}{k!}\\ &=\frac{100!}{100^{100}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{99}
\left( \frac {100^{k+1}}{k!} - \frac{100^k}{(k-1)!}\right)+\frac{100!}{100^{99}}\\ &=
\frac{100!}{100^{100}} 
\left(
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{99} \frac {100^{k+1}}{k!} -
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{98} \frac{100^{k+1}}{k!}\right)+\frac{100!}{100^{99}}\\&=
\frac{100!}{100^{100}} 
\left(
\frac{100^{100}}{99!} +
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{98} \frac {100^{k+1}}{k!} -
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{98} \frac{100^{k+1}}{k!}
-\frac{100^1}{0!}
\right)+\frac{100!}{100^{99}}\\
&= 
100-\frac{100!}{100^{99}}+\frac{100!}{100^{99}}=100.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I see. I fixed my answer too. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Nice answer, btw (+1).